# Open Line profile from native app

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Anyone here know the url scheme that can navigate to a specific Line profile by Line ID?

I have tested that I can open Line app with this url scheme "line://".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this URL themes that are presented by Line.

```
Your Channel Web Application can be launched with the following line scheme:

line://ch/[Channel ID]
To pass parameters to your application via the line scheme above, append the parameters to the line scheme as shown below:

line://ch/[Channel ID]/param1/param2?key1=value1&key2=value2
For example, if the entry URL is https://entry.url/page, the passed parameters will be appended as follows:

https://entry.url/page/param1/param2?key1=value1&key2=value2
Note: When adding parameters to the line scheme, make sure to add a slash (/) after the Channel ID as shown below:

line://ch/[Channel ID]/?key1=value1
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, Sorry for late reply, I am really appreciate for your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Oleg How to get Channel ID in line?